# SQL foreign key,not able to set foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE students(
  student_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  first_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  last_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  advisor_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (student_id),
  KEY advisor_id (advisor_id),
  CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (advisor_id) REFERENCES advisors (advisor_id)
);
```

Comment: What is the error? Can you add more details? Give us the DDL for advisors table too.

Comment: you should add what error you got and environment at least

Comment: Add the `Advisors` table definition as well.

Comment: Where should I set the constraint name for the foreign key.Do I need to set it to same as primary key constraint name.

Comment: Not able how? What was the error? Just dumping your code with no explanation makes for a very poor question. See the Help Centre: _"Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, **a specific problem or error** and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."_

Answer (score -1):

```
CONSTRAINT (advisor_id) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES advisors (advisor_id)
```